# Using DefaultAzureCredential with Ubuntu + Rider

Tags: c#, .net, linux, jetbrains-rider, defaultazurecredential

I am attempting to run a .NET 6.0 project locally on my Ubuntu machine using rider. The project using the DefaultAzureCredential class but when I trying running it gives the following error

> "DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included
> credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information.
> [https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot\n-](https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot%5Cn-)
> EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment
> variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for
> more information.
> [https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot\n-](https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot%5Cn-)
> ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple
> attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity
> endpoint.\n- Operating system Linux 5.19.0-26-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP
> PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov 23 20:44:15 UTC 2022 isn't supported.\n-
> Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode
> Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information.
> [https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot\n-](https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot%5Cn-)
> Please run 'az login' to set up account\n- PowerShell is not
> installed."

I tried installing the Azure Cli and using az login which logs me in successfully but that does not resolve the error. I also tried installing the Azure Toolkit in rider and signing in through that with a 'device code'. Again that works successfully but when running the application I still getting the same issue.

This same project work fine using rider or visual studio in Windows, so it seems to be something about this class being unable to consume credentials on my Linux machine that is not a problem when using a Windows.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue here

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default AzureCliCredential should read the credentials from `$HOME/.azure` so it should be able to read it. Maybe values of `$HOME` or `$AZURE_CONFIG_DIR` differ (do you run app as a root maybe? Or in some container?)

I'd suggest setting `includeInteractiveCredentials` to `true` in constructor:

```cs
new DefaultAzureCredential(true)
```

This way, if credentials are not found, it should open a browser to allow authentication

Answer (score 2):

I've tried installing the Azure Developer CLI tool and logging in. This solved my issue with DefaultAzureCredential not <s>detecting my subscriptions</s> retrieving values from KeyVault.

Comment: I no longer work for the company where I was having the issue and I never did get it working. 

With respect to your comment, I did try the CLI tool back then and I could not get it working. However my issue wasn't with access to my subscriptions, it was the project trying to retrieve secrets from the KeyVault we had setup.

Comment: @backwardsx I was having that exact issue, when trying to retrieve secret values from KeyVault using the SDK with DefaultAzureCredential it would fail and the response body mentioned that the authentication methods included Azure Developer CLI. Once I installed it, logged in then it was able to work without issues.